# Yandex.Maps JS API: Поиск кластеров попадающих в круг

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

```
Пример:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fb4exvju/4/

Имеется карта с около 1,5 тысяч меток. При перетаскивании круга на точки, они выбираются и меняют свой цвет. Необходимо, чтоб метки кластеров тоже меняли цвет. По факту, точки входящие в кластер выбираются, нужно просто менять цвет метки кластера. Как мне найти кластеры, попадающие в область круга?

UPD (нашёл решение): http://jsfiddle.net/fb4exvju/5/

Comment: у вас `objects` это массив маркеров, поведение задано только для него

Comment: посмотрите в сторону `Clusterer`

Comment: Я пытался переопределить метод Clusterer.createCluster. Поведение при отрисовке кластера меняется. Но вот как отлавливать событие наведения круга на кластер не придумал

Comment: ObjectManager используете? посмотрите этот пример https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager_events

Comment: Насколько я понял, ObjectManager не работает с geoQuery. https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi/56f0e57901d12f2588dfcb6e

Comment: а зачем вам там geoQuery? без него нельзя определить точки в круге? вместо мыши (как в примере по ссылке) нельзя адаптировать круг?

Comment: Пытаюсь сделать, как вы советуете. http://jsfiddle.net/yzskctwj/1/
Но, получается, что события ObjectManager'а не срабатывают, когда тащу круг над метками.

Comment: Посмотрите на такое решение, наверняка его можно улучшить. http://jsfiddle.net/zraL6xc7/

Comment: Спасибо всем. Нашлось решение.